# C++ write a function that interlaces the content from 2 vectors in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to write a function that takes two vectors as arguments (int) and returns a vector...
now in the function I have to interlace the values from the 2 vectors and put them (interlaced) in a new vector, e.g:

```
vector<int> vec1 = {1,2,3, 4, 5,6,7};
vector<int> vec2 = {10,11,12};
=> Output vec 3 = 1,10,2,11,3,12,4,5,6,7
```

the vectors can have different lenght... how can I make this? I tried:

```
vector<int>  entrelace(vector<int> a , vector<int> b) {
    vector<int> vec3(a.size()+b.size());        
    size_t i(0);
    size_t j(0);
    size_t k(0);
    size_t t(0);

    while ( t< vec3.size()) {

            if (i < a.size()) {
                vec3[k] = a[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
            if (j < b.size()) {
                vec3[k] = b[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }       
        }
        t++;

    /**
    while ( i< (a.size() + b.size()) )
    {
        if (t < a.size()) {
            vec3.push_back(a[t]);
            t++;
            k++;
        }
        if (h < b.size()) {
            vec3.push_back(b[h]);
            h++;
            k++;
        }
    i++;    
    }
    * **/
    return vec3;
}
```

Comment: Why is the `t++` **outside** the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly correct.  You just need to increment `t` every time you set an element in `vec3`

```
while ( t< vec3.size()) {
    if (i < a.size()) {
        vec3[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    if (j < b.size()) {
        vec3[k] = b[j];
        k++;
        j++;
        t++;
    }       
}
```

As an aside, indenting your code more carefully would have helped you spot that `t++` was happening outside the `while` loop.

Also, as john notes, `k` and `t` are duplicating work.  The code could be simplified to

```
while (k < vec3.size()) {
    if (i < a.size()) {
        vec3[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    if (j < b.size()) {
        vec3[k++] = b[j++];
    }       
}
```

Comment: But written like this you can see that having both `k` and `t` is unnecessary. One of them can be removed.

Comment: @john You just beat me to it.  I wanted to show a solution with minimal deviation from the original code first.  I've added a simplified version now.

Comment: OK sorry about that, but you beat me to having answer in the first place!

Comment: @john No criticism intended.  It was a good comment and well worth posting.